# Merge columns and then insert item in table

Tags: tables

I would like to combine two columns and then insert items in the merged columns, But my code is working. The desire look of the table is as the attached picture shows. 
Please help!

```
\begin{tabular}{p{11cm}c}   
&\multirow{2}{*}{CBS}}\\
\textbf{M.Sc. in Finance}& \\
&Sep 2016 - July 2018\\
Main courses:&\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item Corporate Finance, International Business Finance, Entrepreneurial Finance 
    \item Accounting
\end{itemize}}
\end{tabular}
```

[image: example of the desire table]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! itemize doesn't work in column types `c`, `l` and `r`. you should use `p` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert a list in standard cells which by definition are one-lined. You have to use paragraph-like specifier. Here is a solution with `tabularx` and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent{\sffamily\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xc@{}}
&\multirow{2}{*}{CBS}\\
\textbf{M.Sc. in Finance}& \\
&Sep 2016 - July 2018\\
Main courses:&\\
\multicolumn{2}{>{\compress}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{%
\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, after=\vspace{-\topsep}]
    \item Corporate Finance, International Business Finance, Entrepreneurial Finance
    \item Accounting
\end{itemize}}
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This code is working. I am a beginner and it is a challenge for me to understand it.

Comment: Fell free to ask for any questions. I admit  the code is not entirely easy  for a novice. For instance, one of the problems when inserting a list in a cell is that it inserts  vertical spacing at the beginning and at the end, w.r.t. the surrounding text – except if it starts a minipage. The `\compress` directive is inserted at the beginning of the`p {...}` cell is here to fool LaTeX and make it believe we're starting a minipage. Anyway, you should take a look at the documentation of `tabularx` and `enumitem` (which uses a powerful system of keys to customise list environments).